# Trying to one class constructor to use some of the parameters from another class constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor, constructor-overloading

Sorry, this may be an easy resolve but i'm having troubles writing code for the creation of one object which will be using parameters from another class constructors arguments in Java.  Essentially, I have this Inv object that has certain parameters, and I'm trying to create a Warehouse object using only certain parameters from the Inv object, that will then be used in a Warehouse Transaction class.  Could i do an if statement within the Inv objects constructor? Anywho, I will then later push this object onto a stack, but I couldn't develop the logic for the creation of that second object.  Help please, I'm super new to this.

```
public class InvTrans
```

{

```
private int InvTransIndex = 0;
private Inv[] transactionArray;

public InvTrans()
{
    this.transactionArray = new Inv[100];
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    InvTrans widget = new InvTrans();



    Inv order1 = new Inv("March 5th, 2016", "Received", 20, 0001, 2.10, 2.20);
    Inv order2 = new Inv("March 6th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0002, 2.10, 2.50);
    Inv order3 = new Inv("March 7th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0003, 2.10, 2.50);
    Inv order4 = new Inv("March 12th, 2016", "Sold", 140, 0004, 2.40, 2.60);


    widget.addLine(order1);
    widget.addLine(order2);
    widget.addLine(order3);
    widget.addLine(order4);



    for (int counter = 0; counter < widget.transactionArray.length; counter++)
    {
        widget.transactionArray[counter].display();
    }

}

public void addLine(Inv a)
{

    transactionArray[InvTransIndex] = a;
    InvTransIndex = InvTransIndex + 1;
}
}

class Inv
{
String date, type;
int units, referenceNumber;
double costPerUnit, pricePerUnit;

Inv(String d, String t, int u, int r, double c, double p) {
    this.date = d;
    this.type = t;
    this.units = u;
    this.referenceNumber = r;
    this.costPerUnit = c;
    this.pricePerUnit = p;


    Warehouse warehouseTransaction = new Warehouse(this.date, this.type, this.units, this.costPerUnit);

}

public void display()
{
     System.out.println(this.date + "\t" + this.type + "\t" + this.units + "\t\t\t\t\t" + this.referenceNumber + "\t\t\t\t\t" + this.costPerUnit + "\t\t\t" + this.pricePerUnit);
}
}    

public class Warehouse
{
    String date, type = "";
    int units = 0;
    double costPerUnit = 0;
    Warehouse(String d, String t, int u, double c)
    {
        date = d;
        type = t;
        units = u;
        costPerUnit = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to accomplish.  Normally, you have a warehouse, and items stored in the warehouse.

Comment: If you want to create the Warehouse object each time you create an Inv, what is the problem with your current implementation? I would juste make the warehouse a class variable so you can access it later

Comment: @Toaster I was trying to figure out how to create a warehouse object each time an Inv object was created, the parameters from Inv to satisfy it.  I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: ... But that is what you do already... Or do you want to create the Warehouse from outside of the constuctor?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to construct it outside the constructor.  Sorry, I'm having a hard time explaining what my intentions are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Factory pattern:

Create a class called InvFactory. This class will have access to the Warehouse (By the way, a warehouse is a place were you store all your items... Creating a new object Warehouse each time you creat an Inv doesn't really make sense to me. Here I'll call these objects WarehouseItem instead). When you want to create an Inv, you will call the factory instead of the Inv constructor

```
public class InvFactory
{ 
    private LinkedList<WarehouseItem> _warehouse = new LinkedList<WarehouseItem;

    public CreateInv(String d, String t, int u, int r, double c, double p)
    {
        Inv inv = new Inv(d, t, u, r, c, p);
        _warehouse.add(new WarehouseItem(d, t, u, c);
        return inv;
    }

    public LinkedList<WarehouseItem> getWarehouse()
    {
        return _warehouse;
    }
}
```

In you main method, you can then replace

```
Inv order1 = new Inv("March 5th, 2016", "Received", 20, 0001, 2.10, 2.20);
Inv order2 = new Inv("March 6th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0002, 2.10, 2.50);
Inv order3 = new Inv("March 7th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0003, 2.10, 2.50);
Inv order4 = new Inv("March 12th, 2016", "Sold", 140, 0004, 2.40, 2.60);
```

by

```
InvFactory factory = new InvFactory();

Inv order1 = factory.CreateInv("March 5th, 2016", "Received", 20, 0001, 2.10, 2.20);
Inv order2 = factory.CreateInv("March 6th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0002, 2.10, 2.50);
Inv order3 = factory.CreateInv("March 7th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0003, 2.10, 2.50);
Inv order4 = factory.CreateInv("March 12th, 2016", "Sold", 140, 0004, 2.40, 2.60);
```

And At that point, you can see all the items in a list by calling.

```
factory.getWarehouse();
```

I hope this helps